# How to find all the smallest sets not contained in any other set

Tags: python, set

I have a bunch of items which have been sorted in different sets. These sets might have not null intersection between them. How can I find all the sets that are not contained in any of the existing sets?

For example:

- items: a,b,c,d
- sets: {a,b,c}, {a, b}, {a}, {a,b,c,d}, {b,d,c}

In this case the result should be: {a}, {b,d,c}

- {a,b,c,d} contains {a,b,c} contains {a, b} contains {a}
- {a,b,c,d} contains {b,d,c}

My approach would be to create a graph with:

- nodes are the sets
- there is an edege between set 1 and set 2 if set 1 is contained in set 2

Once I build the graph the solution will be the edges without predecessors (or incoming edges).

```
G=nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from([frozenset({'a', 'b', 'c'}),frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'a'}), frozenset({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}), frozenset({'b', 'd', 'c'})])

G.add_edges_from([(n, m) for n in G for m in G if n!=m if n<m])

print([n for n, in_degree in G.in_degree() if in_degree == 0])
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you're trying to find out the sets *not* contained in other sets, why the solution would be {a} and {b,c,d}?

Comment: The add_edges_from call seems to take quadratic time, correct? In that case your method doesn't seem any better than a brute force subset test like this ```[set_ for set_ in allsets if not any(otherset.issubset(set_) for otherset in allsets if otherset is not set_)]```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other ways without `networkx`:

```
sorted_sets = sorted(sets, key=len, reverse=True)
minimal = []
while sorted_sets:
    s = sorted_sets.pop()
    for m in minimal:
        if m <= s:
            break
    else:
        minimal.append(s)
```

or

```
frozen_sets = {frozenset(s) for s in sets}
minimal= set()
while frozen_sets:
    s = frozen_sets.pop()
    remove = set()
    for m in minimal:
        if m <= s:
            break
        elif s < m:
            remove.add(m)
    else:
        minimal.add(s)
        minimal -= remove
```

Output for

```
sets = [{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a"}, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {"b", "d", "c"}]
```

is

```
[{'a'}, {'c', 'd', 'b'}]
```

```
{frozenset({'a'}), frozenset({'c', 'd', 'b'})}
```